# knockout.js click to edit, don't switch back on blur

Tags: knockout.js

I am fairly new to knockoutJS and cannot figure out how to use the hasfocus binding to allow me to 'click to edit' but require a button to save.

I have set up my code (based on two of RP Niemeyer's incredible fiddles) such that when I click a label, I get an editing input box (as expected). The problem comes in using the hasfocus binding.

This is my 'clickToEdit' binding (virtually identical to the second fiddle mentioned below except with the addition of accept and cancel icons):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickToEdit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            link = document.createElement("a"),

            editField = document.createElement("span");
            input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("id", "txt_" + element);
                input.setAttribute("placeholder", observable());
            acceptButton = document.createElement("i");
                acceptButton.className = "icon-ok";
                acceptButton.setAttribute("data-bind", "click: $root.acceptElementEdit");
            cancelButton = document.createElement("i");
                cancelButton.className = "icon-repeat";
                cancelButton.setAttribute("data-bind", "click: $root.cancelElementEdit");
            editField.appendChild(input);
            editField.appendChild(acceptButton);
            editField.appendChild(cancelButton);

            element.appendChild(link);
            element.appendChild(editField);

        observable.editing = ko.observable(false);
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(link, {
            text: observable,
            hidden: observable.editing,
            click: function() {
                observable.editing(true);
            }
        });

        //Apply 'editing' to the whole span
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(editField, {
            visible: observable.editing,
        });
        //Apply the value and the hasfocus bindings to the input field
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(editField.children[0], {
            value: observable,
            //hasfocus: true
        });
    }
};
```

I want the input box to become immediately focused when it becomes visible, but I do not want it to become hidden on blur. I would like to make use of a protected observable (thanks again RP) to use save/cancel on edit.

If there were an update to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X9rRa/ that would focus the first field when the edit button is clicked, or an update to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2jg2F/2/ where unfocusing the input box did not cause it to disappear, I could probably take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to add a `focused` sub-observable to the name field, bind `hasfocus` against it, and set it to true when selecting an item.

So, an item would look like:

```
var Item = function(name, quantity) {
    this.name = ko.protectedObservable(name);
    this.name.focused = ko.observable();
    this.quantity = ko.protectedObservable(quantity);
};
```

and when selecting an item you would do:

```
this.editItem = function(item) {
    self.selectedItem(item);
    item.name.focused(true);
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ks3Cj/

You could even avoid the sub-observable and just put a `hasfocus: true` on the input and it will become focused when the "edit" template is used, but I would probably be a bit more explicit about it like in the sample above.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this. I'm not quite sure why I couldn't make it work like this, but I very much appreciate your help. If it's not too much trouble, could you possibly advise on how this might be wrapped up in the clickToEdit binding?

Comment: I've figured out how to incorporate both with a little more documentation reading and a lot of trial and error. Accepting this as the answer, and thank you very much!